# Finding memory and CPU time bottlenecks in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, memory-leaks, cakephp-2.0, cpu-usage

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805317/performance-tuning-cakephp-application) but it doesn't fit my solution.
I need to find out memory and CPU time bottlenecks in my CakePHP 2 application.
With `microtime` and `memory_get_usage` in controller actions I found out some clues. I fixed some of with this. But it is so hard to diagnose every controller action one by one.

I need to log CPU and memory loads for each of my actions. I'm planning to put 2 global variables in my controller. And calculate them inside beforeFilter and afterFilter and log them for checking afterwards.
Is this proper way or can you recommend another solution?

```
class AppController extends Controller {

var $requestStartTime = 0;
var $requestDifTime = 0;
var $memoryBefore  = 0;
var $memoryAfter = 0;

function beforeFilter() {
     $requestStartTime  = microtime(true);
     $memoryBefore  =memory_get_usage(true);
}

function afterFilter() {
    $requestDifTime = microtime(true) - $requestStartTime;
    $memoryAfter = memory_get_usage(true);

    $myFile = TMP.'logs'.DS.'mylog.txt';
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
    $string = "start time:" . $requestStartTime .
              " dif time: " . $requestDifTime 
              " memory usage: " . $memoryBefore . " and " . $memoryAfter
              ."\n";
    fwrite($fh,$string);
    fclose($fh);
}

}
```

Comment: Don't forget about xdebug. It can provide cruical information about your bottlenecks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best tool I have found when working with PHP, and any PHP framework including CakePHP is "[Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/)". Xdebug is a PHP extension that can be enabled to provide profiling output files that can be analysed with tools like "[Webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/)" (or CallGrind, and others).

Webgrind will take the xdebug trace files and provide you with a visual tree of time spent and resource allocation. This enables you to selectively drill down into the method and function calls made during the execution of a system, and find where time is being lost, and where resources are being allocated.

In addition, Xdebug enables you to start debugging your application. You can allocate breakpoints, and pause execution, modify values and step through your code providing you with a more flexible debugging approach to development.

This has been a valuable tool while building things with CakePHP, and also while building on the core for CakePHP itself.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But for that website I use shared hosting and I don't have shell access. Although I can try the performance in my local copy, possibly I won't have access to shell of my host.

Comment: Your performance testing and profiling should be done locally. Never use Xdebug in production as it causes additional load on the server.

Comment: in the code profile for a cake app, where can I see my code?